# Do I have to buy Minecraft from Microsoft Store all over again?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, microsoft-store

So, I recently just got a new gaming computer but I realized that when I tried to install Minecraft on the new one, it had asked me for money again. Is there any way to transfer the bought Minecraft onto my current pc?

Comment: On which store did you purchase it?

Comment: The microsoft store.

Comment: Oh, I got it back. Thanks pinck! Also o2h2o, I had gotten bedrock version.

Comment: Good to know! I'll post that as the answer then

Answer (score 1):

Most software that you buy directly from Microsoft comes as a digital download that you can download, install, or reinstall. After you purchase software, the download will be shown in your [Order history](https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders). If you used the same email, of course.

Comment: Just to add a bit more info, make sure you have logged in with the same Microsoft account. As well as this, there are many versions of Minecraft, such as the collector's edition, and it seems new ones keep getting added all the time, your library can be viewed by clicking the book icon in the bottom left of the store and your game should be there available for download.